# Пунктуация в сложном предложении

Tags: пунктуация

в каком варианте ответа правильно указаны все цифры , на месте которых в предложении должны стоять запятые?
**

**Ремонтная техника железнодорожного депо сильно устарела (1) и (2) хотя от руководства каждый год приходили указания обновить оборудование (3) денег на это никто не выделял (4) и  все оставалось по-прежнему.****

1)1,2,3

2)3,4

3)2,3

4)2,3,4

Comment: Учите русский язык и делайте домашние задания сами, чтобы потом не позориться безграмотностью. Предлагайте свой вариант ответа, а мы укажем на ошибки, если таковые будут.

Answer (score 0):

Конечно, таняzzzzzzzzzzz задала вопрос некорректно, но предложение, которое вызвало ее сомнения, достоин рассмотрения. Видимо, девочку смутило то, что между частями сложного предложения, связанными сочинительным союзом"и" (цифра 4)запятая не ставится. Здесь, Таня, не так часто случающаяся ситуация, когда у обеих частей сложносочиненного предложения есть общее придаточное предложение - в данном случае "хотя от руководства каждый год приходили указания обновить оборудование". В школах не всегда хватает времени разбирать такие редкие примеры, поэтому  затруднения девочки понятны. Не будем ее упрекать.

Answer (score 0):

Это не редкий, а типичный для ЕГЭ 11 класса пример.Задание №19 "Знаки препинания в сложных предложениях с разными видами союзной и бессоюзной связи". Но, мне кажется, что Татьяну смутило не наличие общего придаточного предложения, а незнание уступительного подчинительного союза "хотя" и неумение поставить вопрос к придаточному уступительному. "...денег на это никто не выделял" НЕСМОТРЯ НА ЧТО? "хотя от руководства каждый год приходили указания обновить оборудование",                    "... все оставалось по-прежнему" НЕСМОТРЯ НА ЧТО? "хотя от руководства каждый год приходили указания обновить оборудование". Два однородных придаточных отвечают на один и тот же вопрос, относятся к одному и тому же предложению, следовательно между ними , как при однородных  членах, перед союзом И запятая не ставится. Таким образом, верный вариант ответа  - 1